# Wrong variance of mean

Tags: variance, bernoulli-distribution, overdispersion

I'm told that the $Var(\overline{x}) \approx Var(X)/N$, where $\overline{x}$ is the mean of $N$ elements from $X$. However, I have a data set where these variances seem to differ by a factor of about 30.

A series of Bernoulli trials is run. The input data consists of numbers of successes and attempts made in an hour. I have some $400000$ trials unevenly distributed in around $1000$ hours. I take $M$ random samples of hours, and calculate their means as sum of successes divided by sum of attempts. I expect that if $E$ is the mean of these $M$ means, then their variance will be $E(1-E)/\text{sample size}$, however the real variance is found to be much bigger.

I suspect this effect in large part due to the uneven distribution of trials in hours and the way I sample them. Is that true? If so, can I correct for it? I tried aggregating hours with few events, but it didn't seem to help. Could something else be causing it? Should I expect the real variance to be correct if I use all the data rather than random samples?

Comment: Your first sentence is true only if the $X_i$'s are independent.

Comment: Can you clarify the part about hours and uneven distribution. Do your samples have different numbers of trials? If so, how do you obtain $N$ for your formula?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala, there could be anywhere from 0 to 20000 trials per hour though most have under 5000. The sample sizes are fairly normally distributed with mean of 100000 and standard deviation of 20000. I take N to be the mean of sample sizes. In this particular sampling the samples do overlap, though I've tried sampling without overlap too without much difference in the ratio of variances.

Comment: Is each individual Bernoulli trial characterized by the same probability of success?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, somewhat. It seems to be 0.04 in the first half and 0.03 in the second. Whether there is some variation in, for example, day vs night probabilities I don't know.

Comment: When you write "$E(1−E)/\text{sample size}$", what do you mean by "sample size"?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, I take many random samples from my data set. They end up having different numbers of trials, as I've described in my reply to JuhoKokkala, regardless of how I try. I take "sample size" to be the mean of of the real sizes.

While my method of sampling may not be perfect, it seems to work alright on fake data. However, I'm having a hard time making my fake data look like the real data.

Comment: This is called overdispersion, search this site. There can be many reasons. We really need much more details and context of your cae.